# Angular/Ionic listen to Ionic-Event

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, events

We have an Ionic-Angular Frontend Application with following Problem:

There is this component:

```
...

export class StepIndicatorComponent {
  @Input() slides: IonSlides;

...

}
```

Now i want to add an event listener to slides for the event "ionSlideDidChange". Everytime the event gets triggered, a method should be called.

I tried rxjs, Hostlistener, but theses are only for DOM objects.

I know i can can add the methodcall for the event in the html, but in this case i have to do it in the .ts component file.

Any ideas?

Thx

---

Ion Slides API:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/slides

Answer (score 1):

`IonSlides` is an element, you can't use `@Input` declaration. You can simply bind the event on the element itself

```
<ion-slides (ionSlideDidChange)="onSlideChange($event)">
  <ion-slide>
    <h1>Slide 1</h1>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

See the example here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-g3sehf

Comment: thanks for your answer. The @Input declaration works (i can work with it in the .ts class of the other component),  thats not the problem. I also know the way to bind the event like you mentioned.
I just want to add a listener to the event in the other components .ts file